# Implementing my shell using c, Change the directory

Tags: shell

Implementing my own shell

I did not post the whole code to save your time,

briefly i used exec() to execute the command lines

my problem is clarified in a comment line below

thanks for any help

```
int main()
{
int pid[2];
char inbuf[10];
printf("\n\nSimple Shell using C\n");


char hostname[1024];
hostname[1023] = '\0';
gethostname(hostname, 1023);
char resolved_path[100];
realpath("./", resolved_path);
printf("Maram @%s :<%s>$ ", hostname,resolved_path);  //MY PROBLEM: For cd command ex: cd Desktop/Folder.. does not go in this directory and the resolved path does not change 

while(1){
    printf("[my shell] :");
    gets(inbuf);
    if(fork()){
        wait();
    }else{
        pip(inbuf, 0, 1);
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

/// ALSO, how can I print a command not found if an entered command line is not correct?

Comment: This question is far too meandering as it is; a good StackOverflow question asks only one thing, and includes only code directly relevant to that one thing (but is also sufficient to be testable; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://sscce.org/ for guidelines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in this program do you call `chdir()` -- which is the only way to change your current process's directory (barring functional equivalents such as `fchdir()`; which still retain the fundamental restriction that they impact only the current process and not its parents).

Using an exec-family call to launch an external program which changes *its own* directory has no effect -- that program's directory is separate from your shell's. The shell must change its own directory without forking if you want to have any effect.

Comment: thanks! any idea to check if a command is not found? to give the user an error

Comment: That should be asked as its own question.